# Two-photon absorption fluorescence of air

Tags: atmospheric-science, air, absorption, photon-emission, fluorescence

I'm wondering if there are any major constituents of air which are capable of undergoing two-photon absorption and ultimately fluorescing in the visible spectrum. The original wavelengths of the photons getting absorbed aren't really an issue, nor is the intensity of the light -- just as long as the photon emitted is between 390 and 700 nm. Ideally the two photons would be of different wavelengths (is two-photon absorption even possible with two photons of different wavelength? I've not been able to find much literature on that at all), but it's not too big of a deal if they're the same. I've seen some papers which would suggest that two-photon absorption fluorescence is possible for atomic nitrogen and atomic oxygen in atmospheric plasma, but I've seen nothing that gives any information either way as far as diatomic oxygen or nitrogen, and nothing about anything in regular atmosphere.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at any papers on singlet delta oxygen?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, here is a link with background information about two photon absorption. [rp photonics](https://www.rp-photonics.com/two_photon_absorption.html). In general, you can excite any allowed transition with a photon of energy $\Delta E = E_2 - E_1$ where $E_2$ and $E_1$ are the energies of the upper and lower states of the atom/molecule. 2 photon absorption is simply exciting the transition with 2 simultaneous photons whos energies sum to $\Delta E $. So there are certainly 2 photon transitions of molecular oxygen and nitrogen.

The reason you don't see many papers about them is because the single photon absorption wavelengths for molecular species are generally easy to reach with our current laser technology, and single photon absorption cross-sections are much larger.

I expect that there are either 1 or 2 photon transitions of molecular oxygen and nitrogen in the wavelength range you are asking about. you can inspect their energy level diagrams (Grotrian diagrams) to see what ground state transitions are available.